# Issues with event bookings

Tags: civievent, stripe

We are running Civi 5.65.2 on WP 6.4.2 with strip 6.10.2  We are getting a number of erroros where the booking fails when they try to submit it  an entry appears in the stripe dashboard as a cancelled payment, but nothing in civicrm-  I have not seen any consistent pattern yet (we could have multiple errors).
looking at the log files I see the following  warnings seen

Any Thoughts?

[warning] Participant record without event ID. You have invalid data in your database!

How do I find out more information about where this is coming from.

The second ?related error I get is

Stripe(5): doPayment: Stripe\Exception\InvalidRequestException: This PaymentIntent's statement_descriptor could not be updated because it has a status of requires_action. You may only update the statement_descriptor of a PaymentIntent with one of the following statuses: requires_payment_method, requires_confirmation, requires_capture.

Any Thoughts?

Comment: You could start with this small patch which will at least tell you which participant id: https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/pull/28972/files